# Set feedback fraction of inverting input configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

Suppose we have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0a5uz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can we set the feedback fraction of this closed loop configuration?

Comment: What do you want to set it to and what is your definition of feedback fraction?

Comment: The feedback fraction is equal to the feedback signal divided by the output signal.I want it to set it to 1 so the overall gain of the closed loop configuration is equal to 1.

Comment: Do you know how resistor voltage dividers work? Are you able to calculate the feedback fraction based on Vout, Rf, Rs and Vinv? It's just a simple potential divider formula that gets you the voltage at Vin- however, if you want the fraction to be unity then Rs must be open circuit and now you have no relevance in the circuit for Vinv.

Comment: Can you give me the formula? I know how voltage dividers work but when dealing with negative feedback I get confused.